# How to join uuid columns in hibernate and jpa?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, uuid

I am using UUID as primary key values for my database. The UUID is generated on Java side and placed into a PostgreSQL DB which has a varchar column marked as Primary Key.

I am now trying to join two tables in Hibernate using this column. I used to have int/long data type columns and it worked fine. Then switched to UUID and having issues.

My MailDataSource.java class.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
@Column(name = "mail_datasource_uuid", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private String mailDataSourceUuid;
```

My Content.java class which should take the UUID which was generated in the MailDataSource.java class and store it in column content_datasource_uuid.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
@Column(name = "content_uuid", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private String contentUuid;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="content_datasource_uuid")
private Mc360MailDataSource contentDatasourceUuid;
```

The error:

```
Field error in object 'content' on field 'contentDatasourceUuid': rejected 
value [2d001537-bf43-4b99-a759-1134da8aa1b8]; codes [typeMismatch.content.contentDatasourceUuid,
typeMismatch.contentDatasourceUuid,typeMismatch.com.data.entity.MailDataSource,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: 
codes [content.contentDatasourceUuid,contentDatasourceUuid]; 
arguments []; default message [contentDatasourceUuid]]; default 
message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' 
to required type 'com.data.entity.MailDataSource' for property 'contentDatasourceUuid'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: 
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] 
for value '2d001537-bf43-4b99-a759-1134da8aa1b8'; nested exception 
is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: 
"2d001537-bf43-4b99-a759-1134da8aa1b8"]
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Could you please provide more information/code? There's obviously still a `java.lang.Long` somewhere in the IDs. Also you posted the id of `MailDataSource.java` but your many-to-one seems to be a `Mc360MailDataSource`

Comment: Thank you. Your comment raised another question. What about the Repository classes? The problem came from there. I had `JpaRepository<MailDataSource, Long>`, when it should have been `JpaRepository<MailDataSource, String>`

Comment: Yes, this would have been the first place to look if you posted the repo classes :-). Btw. you can also use `UUID` directly instead of `String`

Comment: Will give it a try, thanks. You want to post the answer then I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from the Repository classes.

I had `JpaRepository<MailDataSource, Long>`, when it should have been `JpaRepository<MailDataSource, String>`